# Multilingual contribution and registration pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, profile, multilingual

I have a couple of forms on my multilingual website (French and Dutch, Wordpress + WPML plugin).
I translated signup profiles and contribution pages in both languages.

I can succesfully call the original (Dutch) page with an url like domain.com/nl/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=1 but I can't figure out how to display the French version.

Can anybody help me here?